# hyperref package: how to color citations only

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to use the hyperref package to color citations only, but it seems that it colors every link.

For example here:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor  = blue,
        colorlinks = true,
    }
    
\begin{document}
        
\tableofcontents
\section{This title should be in red in the TOC}
        
This citation \cite{a} is blue.
        
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
   \bibitem{a} Andros, Using hyperref for a citation, StackExchange, 2022.
\end{thebibliography}
        
\end{document}
```

I would like the citation to be blue, but I don't want the items in the table of contents to be red.

Thanks

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]. The easiest solutions is probably to set all other colours to match the text colour

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the Beamer template Metropolis and I don't know where to get the text colour (it is not black).

Comment: Don't use colour links with beamer. This will destroy the carefully constructed themes in a lot of very unexpected places.

Comment: (and the text colour for metropolis is `black!2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not activate `colorlinks` with beamer. This can break the carefully constructed colour themes in sometimes very surprising places.

Instead you could change the text colour for the citation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@citex}{\color{blue}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@citex}{\color{normal text.fg}\xspace}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
        
\begin{frame}
        
This citation \cite{a} is blue.
        
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
   \bibitem{a} Andros, Using hyperref for a citation, StackExchange, 2022.
\end{thebibliography}
        
\end{frame}        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Your example works fine, but it seems not to be working for me, and maybe that's because I am using BibLaTeX...

Comment: Sorry about that! But your solution works fine and I have switched to standard bibliography, thanks!